# DexOpt: Illegal method access

Tags: java, android, android-4.4-kitkat, dexopt, android-runtime

I have a location based app which worked fine till yesterday but when I run it on my phone now it acts weird.

Below is my logcat which shows up errors that I've never seen or heard before

```
07-07 14:17:25.548: D/ActivityThread(24383): handleBindApplication:com.example.loc_update
07-07 14:17:25.553: D/ActivityThread(24383): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
07-07 14:17:25.553: D/ActivityThread(24383): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
07-07 14:17:25.573: I/dalvikvm(24383): DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
07-07 14:17:25.573: I/dalvikvm(24383): Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>, referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.<init>
07-07 14:17:25.573: W/dalvikvm(24383): VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
07-07 14:17:25.573: D/dalvikvm(24383): VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
07-07 14:17:25.683: W/dalvikvm(24383): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4162bce0)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383): Process: com.example.loc_update, PID: 24383
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.loc_update/com.example.loc_update.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2228)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5152)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at com.example.loc_update.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:107)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6020)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
07-07 14:17:25.688: E/AndroidRuntime(24383):    ... 12 more
```

Note: I installed android 4.4.4 custom rom yesterday. Is it because of this reason?

Comment: Unless you're the developer of the app and trying to correct the code, you're on the wrong site. If you *are* the developer of the app, it would be a good idea to include the code that triggers the exception.

Comment: I have the same error `DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init>`, my new app worked perfect, I was adding a settings feature and all of a sudden, BAM! my whole app background goes blank, I get "null" exception messages, etc. did you ever figure it out?!

Comment: @Matt I had to do something with the initialization of UI elements( ex. TextView, Button, etc) and it worked fine.
Are you adding settings Menu item ?

Comment: @Vinay, I finally figured out my problem. it seems I accidentally commented out the  setContentView in my onCreate method (or maybe it was in the main activity), but anyway, about 2 or 3 hours of researching/debugging I finally found the problem. (Created a dummy activity, and copied snippets to it until it stopped working--then I realized my problem)